# Failure installing sbt: "Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException:"

Tags: sbt

When I try to install error messages, it fails to download. I get error messages like this:

```
[error] Server access Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching repo.scala-sbt.org found. url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-pgp/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.3/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I can confirm, when accessing via my browser, that the certificate installed for the domain `repo.scala-sbt.org` is actually the certificate for `repo.typesafe.com`, and this seems to be the source of the error. It doesn't appear to be a DNS issue as `http://repo.scala-sbt.org/` (insecure) works.

Comment: Chronologically, `repo.scala-sbt.org` was shut down first, and then I set up a new redirection proxy, which does not have the `repo.scala-sbt.org` certificate yet. We are waiting on MX validation currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2125 for the workarounds. Specifically "http" should not be used.

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("fix-sbt-plugin-releases", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

**Edit**: This issue is now resolved. No workarounds should be required.

Comment: March 2016 - happened again. Added the above workaround as first line in my `plugins.sbt` and works fine (with some security errors though).

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround, add the file `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/temp.sbt` with the following contents:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("fix-sbt-plugin-releases", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

You'll still see the error, but sbt will be able to find the dependency for which it is searching when accessing `https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases` directly (the place to which repo.scala-sbt.org presently redirects).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading nss package on CentOS worked for me.

`sudo yum upgrade nss`